# Migrate-mongo autogenerated id-s in different environments

Tags: mongodb, migration, migrate-mongo

I use migrate-mongo to run my migrations across dev/stage/prod environments.
For my documents I use the autogenerated mongo id-s.
But when I run an insertion script like this

```
let result = await db.collection("regions").insertMany(
[{
                region: "Asia",
                hostedIn: "Singapore",
                token: "asia",
                order:1
},
```

using migrate-mongo it generates different id-s for each environments.
What is the best practice to keep ids the same across the environments?

Answer (score 0):

To keep the same Id's you literally have to read the documents first, then insert them.

```
const existingDocs = await db.collection("regions").find({}).toArray();
let result = await db.collection("regions").insertMany(existingDocs)
```

Another option is to pre-generate those ids and then use them in your script.

```
let result = await db.collection("regions").insertMany(
[{
     region: "Asia",
     hostedIn: "Singapore",
     token: "asia",
     order:1,
     _id: 1
}]
```

Comment: Tom, I can't use the first approach you described because the dev and prod envs should have an access to each other, so I read from dev and write to prod which is not possible.
Do I understand properly that the only solution is using pre-generated ids?

Comment: Yes, no other solution then.